# If $\lim f(x)$ exists and $\lim g(x)$ do not, when $x$ approaches $a$ , why $\lim[f(x)+g(x)]$ does not exist?

Tags: limits, functions

If  $\lim f(x)$ exists and $\lim g(x)$ do not, when $x$ approaches $a$, why $\lim[f(x)+g(x)]$  does not exist?

need some help over here, to prove the above statement

Comment: $\lim \left[f(x)+g(x)\right]$ does not exist, ever, if $\lim f(x)$ exists and $\lim g(x)$ does not. Assuming the limits are as $x$ approaches the same value...

Comment: I am a little confused what you are asking here, but I do know that if one of the limits exists and the other one doesn't, than the sum or difference for that matter of these two limits cannot exist. In order to apply the limit operations on two limits, both need to exist, i.e. approach a finite answer.

Comment: well i updated my question. im yet a bit confused. how can i proove that if limf(x) exists and limg(x) do not, the limit sum lim[f(x) + g(x)] do not exist?

x approaches a

Answer (score 4):

If $\lim [f(x)+g(x)]$ exists then $\lim [[f(x)+g(x)]-f(x)]$ exists, a contradiction since $\lim g(x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Write $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$. Assume otherwise, i.e. $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0}h(x)$ exist. Then we know that also the limit of the difference exists, i.e. $\lim_{x\to x_0}(h(x)-g(x))$. But that is just $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sin x\qquad\text{does not exist}$$
but
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(x+\sin x)=+\infty$$

Comment: $\infty \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: did the OP explicitly asked for a finite limit?

Comment: No, but there are other ways for a limit to not exist. Actually, you've added two functions without limits. Did the OP ask about that?

Comment: What are you saying? $\lim_{x\to+\infty} x=+\infty$ is not a valid existent limit?

Comment: "... the *proper* thing to say is that the function 'diverges' or 'grows without bound'..." [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_involving_infinity)